# Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory in West Europe

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working in a company that would like to utilise the ADF copy activities in order to build a data importer service (or pipeline). Our main intention is: receive data through different channels: FTP, HTTP Endpoints, Blobs etc, and perform custom transformation on those endpoints and store those to our system.
Our main concern is that ADF is not available in North Europe and we want to move our data within that regio. My question is: when ADF is not available in a specific region, if I build an ADF pipeline in a different region, will copy activity transfer the data from our primary region (WE) to where ADF pipeline is stored and then copy back to the ultimate destination?

**EDIT 2016-09-28** 
So to make it clear: can I create ADF Copy Activities in order to copy-transform (using activities)-save some of our data from one point in azure storage (probably blobs) to another point in the same storage or any other storage in the same data center (West Europe). If so, during the pipeline execution are those data going to flow from one data center to another or they will remain within the same center?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADF is available in [North Europe](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/) at this time. Did you perhaps mean to ask about a different region. Our service is currently in West US, East US and North Europe.

In the case of Copy activities: when both the source and destination data stores are in the cloud, the closest available region for Data Movement is used. There is a [mapping of data location to data movement region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-data-movement-activities/#global) available for reference.

In general, the location of a data factory doesn't matter too much. The main purpose of a factory is to invoke jobs/processes on other services. Say for example you were to run a map reduce job on an HDInsight cluster: the factory simply calls the HDI APIs as that service expects them to be called.

Comment: Thank you Brian. Can you please confirm my new updated answer?

Comment: Following the link I see now what you mean. Thank you.